# Difference between pose and cause

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

What's the difference between pose and cause?

For examples:

> pose a problem vs cause a problem
>
> pose a question vs cause a question or bring up a question
>
> pose an issue vs cause an issue

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? If so, what did you learn?

Comment: Actually, my dictionary used the word  'cause' to explain 'pose'. So, I am wondering if there are any differences between these two words.

Comment: I'm sure it used several words to explain pose. So why are you picking on cause? You need more explanation in your question.

Comment: Ok, here is what my dictionary says: "If something poses a problem or a danger, it is the cause of that problem or danger. "

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't be against somebody explaining this difference. I never use "**pose**" cause I can't understand where to use it.

Comment: Well, it's not that common a word, so I don't know whether it matters. One poses for the camera, poses questions to the audience; Putin poses a threat to the world lol. A criminal may pose as a police officer to get the trust of someone. A man might pose as a successful businessman in front of women so that he can pick up a date even though he's not a successful businessman. There are also rare cases like "That question **poses** me" or "That question's a real **poser**" wherein this means "to baffle", or, as the noun "poser", it means a "baffling problem".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, since this seems to flummox more than one person:

> [**pose**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pose) *v*
>   2. To present or constitute: *a crisis that posed a threat to the country's stability.*

Your dictionary uses *cause* (loosely, I believe) to mean *present or constitute*. To my way of thinking, *cause* is not really a good synonym for either of those.

Comment: This is the dictionary I refer to: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pose

Comment: I haven't seen the definition of to present or constitute. Maybe, different dictionaries take this differently I guess.

Comment: Also, Cambridge: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pose

Comment: It defines: to cause something,especially a problem ordifficulty

Comment: @dan: I understand your difficulty, but for me *cause* is a poor choice of words there because it confuses the notion of a "necessary condition" with *any* agent or condition.

Comment: So, from your perspective, what's the difference between 'pose a problem' and 'cause a problem'?

Comment: Let's see if I can draw the distinction for you. To pose a problem is simply to present one; to *cause* a problem is to actively instigate one. Example: having a child poses a problem (to finances, say), while the child itself can *cause* a problem (by breaking something valuable). Then the child's willfulness can *pose* a problem, etc. These are nuances, but nuances can be important.